# Create design template file in PHP

Tags: php, css

I intent to create a template PHP file, this template will only serve the design, not the content. The purpose is to decrease the development time in a sense that when creating a new PHP file or new module, I can only need to concentrate on the main function of that PHP file not the design. Once I created the new file using the template, it should be able to display the consistent design and serve its specific function.

The issue is that I am not sure on how to make the design of the template works and applied to all of the new files created regardless of the location (as long as it is within the root directory).

As an example:

```
root directory (www.example.com): /
homepage (www.example.com/index.php): /index.php
css file: /style/style.css
template file: /template.php
newly created file (www.example.com/subone/find/css/file.php): /subone/find/css/file.php
another newly created file (www.example.com/subtwo/locate/css.php): /subtwo/locate/css.php
```

Content of the homepage (which is created base on the template.php, but the CSS file location is hard coded):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">logo and login form goes here
<div class="nav"> navigation goes here;</div>
</div>
<div id="main">main content goes here;</div>
<div id="footer">footer goes here; </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but, when I created a new file, /subone/find/css/file.php
the location of the css must be changed and specified manually, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">logo and login form goes here
<div class="nav"> navigation goes here</div>
</div>
<div id="main">main content goes here;</div>
<div id="footer">footer goes here;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what I want to achieve is that, when creating a new file (/subone/find/css/file.php), I don't need to do anything, I can straight away concentrate on the main section:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
...style.css is handled automatically
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">logo and login form goes here
<div class="nav"> navigation goes here</div>
</div>
<div id="main">main content goes here;
<?php
//I can continue to edit the file from this line onward
echo "I am concentrating on the main function of file.php right now!!";
?>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer goes here;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

example page can be seen at (only the desired design): neoborn.kodingen.com
I accept any answers as long as it can achieve my intention (template).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use absolute paths when referring to CSS files and other resources in your template file?

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css" />
```

Comment: I have tried it out, it works fine. But, the only issue of using this method is the repetitive task if the directory is changed. Because I need to open every PHP file and replace it one by one. But, thanks to Chuck's answer. It should solve the issue that I just mentioned. Anyway, thanks for the respond. =)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options,

1. Use absolute paths for your css files `<link rel=stylesheet href="/style/style.css">`
2. Use HTML's [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4) element to cause all relative paths on the page relate to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Index.php**

```
<?php define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost'); ?>
```

**Template.php**

```
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/style/style.css ?>" />
```

Comment: I have tried this method as well, but it doesn't work. The $BASE_URL is not declared or does not have any value at all. So, what I can do to solve this issue? and I am not familiar with define() method though. But, I will research on it.

Comment: My mistake. <?php echo BASE_URL; ?> is the correct way to access a defined constant.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a easy to install template engine. That will help speed up development and still give you the freedom to do whatever PHP you like.

Try http://www.raintpl.com/ that should be quick and easy for you to install and get back to coding the pages. If you include it in your PHP inc folder, it will be available for every PHP file you create. So you won't need to add an include line at the top of each PHP file.

Comment: That's a new thing for me. I will explore and give it a try and it sounds cool!! =)